# formatting textInput in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, formatting, textinput

It looks like the default font formatting for the textInput is a bit off. The margin at the top is less than at the bottom.

I've tried the setTextFormat, with `defaultTextFormat` and `setTextFormat` but it's not doing the trick.

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.size = 16;
_autoComplete.textField.defaultTextFormat = tf;
_autoComplete.textField.setTextFormat(tf);
```

Any ideas ???

I'm using Astra's autoComplete, but I don't think this is restricting it, though there is a slight chance that the field has an override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextFormat` will not help you (it's about text color, bold, italic and etc). You may try to do `_autoComplete.textField.autoSize = flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT`.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the height of the TF

tf.height = tf.textHeight + X; // X - is the amount needed for you font to look corectly.